# sqlce in Xenocode

Tags: sql-server-ce, xenocode

I'm using Xenocode in my application so that it works without a .NET framework. I'm using Xenocode Virtual Application Studio(version 6.1). Everything works fine except the .sdf file which I have embedded inside the application directory. actually in the application the instead of SQL server i have used SQL Compact edition(3.5) and i have included the reqired  dll . All the files are working except the ".sdf" file.

Any idea y is that so? Is it because the ".sdf" file is being used when the xenocode after snapshot was taken? if so what is the solution for that? i cannot avoid using it because Xenocode's after snapshot will not recognise the application if it's not running and if I run the application ".sdf" file will be used.

Anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear to me what you've done from your question but I think what's happened is that you either have the actual file as an embedded resource or at least the name of it and Xenocode has obfuscated the name of the resource, so the application can no longer find it. Go into Xenocode and tell it to not obfuscate all of the resources and this will remedy it (assuming my interpretation of the question is correct).

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you've done from your question but I *think* what's happened is that you either have the actual file as an embedded resource or at least the name of it and Xenocode has obfuscated the name of the resource, so the application can no longer find it.  Go into Xenocode and tell it to *not* obfuscate all of the resources and this will remedy it (assuming my interpretation of the question is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply,

Its not as an obfuscated resource. I have added it file application directory and it's present when the files are extracted in the @APPDIR@/@ProgramFiles@ folder. but the file is corrupted so I cannot use it.
In simple if I say means My .sdf file is getting corrupted when i use it with Xenocode. 
I'm not sure for the reason but it might be that as when Xenocode is taking the after snapshot that time the .sdf file is in use by the application and hence it might not be copied in proper format or wat .
I'm not sure for the reason y the .sdf file is corrupted!!!!!!!!
Anyways I found the solution and trying with it.
I'm using Engine.Repair function in my code if its corrupted.
But it's not a good way I feel. I'm bothered why the .sdf file is corrupted!!!!!!

Comment: Please add replies to answers as comments under the answer that you are replying to. If you need to post additional information, simply edit your question :)